# Interrupt a Scanner.readLine call using 2 User Interfaces (GUI and Console) at the same time

Tags: java, model-view-controller, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I have to create a java application which can be used with a Graphic User Interface and a "Console Interface" at the same time (so I use MVC Design Pattern obviously). That's means that a user can switch from one interface to the other at any time they want during the game. My problem is the following:

How can I interrupt my `Scanner.readline` instruction when my model call `notifyObserver()`?

Is Scanner the best class to use in my case or should I prefer another like BufferedReader?

Comment: Linear processed console code does not work well with event-driven paradigms. Yes, create one model for all, but the UI's will need to behave differently.

Comment: Java's "Console Interface" can only read one full line at a time, and cannot be interrupted. Console interface is not good for asynchronous applications, so you should re-think what you're doing.

Comment: You can't create a GUI/Console application that switches from one to the other.  You can create two separate applications where the user can shut one down and start up the other.  Assuming you retain the game state, the user can resume his game.